# One ListView blocks the otherone

Tags: django, django-views

I'm working on a app, and the app has two different ListViews, one of them for posts the other is for news.
Here are the Views:

```
class NewsListView(ListView):
context_object_name = 'news'
model = models.News
template_name = 'posts/news_list.html'


def get_queryset(self):
    return News.objects.all()

class PostsListView(ListView):
context_object_name = 'posts'
model = models.Posts
template_name = 'posts/posts_list.html'

def get_queryset(self):
    return Posts.objects.all()
```

Here is the apps urls.py:

```
urlpatterns=[
url(r'^$',views.NewsListView.as_view(),name='news'),
url(r'^$',views.PostsListView.as_view(),name='posts'),]
```

And here is the projects urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^$',views.IndexView.as_view(),name='index'),
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
url(r'^posts/',include('posts.urls',namespace='posts')),]
```

My problem i that for some reason only one List works, always the one which is is the first one in the apps urls.py.

How can i solve this problem?

Thanks for your help!!!

Answer (score 0):

you need two different links in apps/urls.py like that

```
urlpatterns=[
url(r'^news/$',views.NewsListView.as_view(),name='news'),
url(r'^/posts$',views.PostsListView.as_view(),name='posts'),]
```

and you can try localhost..../appname/news and localhost..../appname/posts 
you are trying load same page in your code